# ¿Cómo cambiar texto por getString en mi ListView?

Tags: java, android

Así relleno los textos en mi ***listview***

```
 String[] titulo = new String[]{
        "Prueba1",
        "Prueba2",
        "Prueba3",
        "Prueba4",
        "Prueba5",
};
```

Cómo puedo hacer para usar ***getString*** para poderlo traducir a cualquier idioma en ***string.xml***

Por ejemplo para otros textos en mi ***clase*** utilizo

> .setTitle(getResources().getString(R.string.text_1));

Cómo puedo hacerlo en este caso? Gracias

Mi código,

***ListViewAdapter:***

```
public class ListViewAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    // Declare Variables
    Context context;
    String[] titulos;
    int[] imagenes;
    LayoutInflater inflater;

    public ListViewAdapter(Context context, String[] titulos, int[] imagenes) {
        this.context = context;
        this.titulos = titulos;
        this.imagenes = imagenes;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return titulos.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        // Declare Variables
        TextView txtTitle;
        ImageView imgImg;

        inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        View itemView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_row, parent, false);

        // Locate the TextViews in listview_item.xml
        txtTitle = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.list_row_title);
        imgImg = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.list_row_image);

        // Capture position and set to the TextViews
        txtTitle.setText(titulos[position]);
        imgImg.setImageResource(imagenes[position]);

        return itemView;
    }
}
```

***Activity:***

```
public class cat_s extends AppCompatActivity {

    ListViewAdapter adapter;

    private CollapsingToolbarLayout collapsingToolbarLayout = null;

 String[] titulo = new String[]{
        "Prueba1",
        "Prueba2",
        "Prueba3",
        "Prueba4",
        "Prueba5",
};

int[]imagenes={
        R.drawable.ic_launcher,
        R.drawable.ic_launcher,
        R.drawable.ic_launcher,
        R.drawable.ic_launcher,
        R.drawable.ic_launcher,
        };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_cat);
        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            getWindow().setNavigationBarColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorbarra_inf));
        }

        ListView listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview_shi);

        listview.startAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.custom_bounce_entry));


        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        final ListView lista = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview_shi);
        adapter = new ListViewAdapter(this, titulo, imagenes);
        lista.setAdapter(adapter);

        lista.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView adapterView, View view, int posicion, long l) {
                switch (posicion) {
                    case 0:
                        Intent as = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), uno.class);
                        startActivity(as);
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        Intent ca = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), dps.class);
                        startActivity(ca);
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        Intent el = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), tres.class);
                        startActivity(el);
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        Intent elne = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), cuatro.class);
                        startActivity(elne);
                        break;
                    case 4:
                        Intent faa = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), cicon.class);
                        startActivity(faa);
                        break;
                }
            }
        });

        collapsingToolbarLayout = (CollapsingToolbarLayout) findViewById(R.id.collapsing_toolbar);
        collapsingToolbarLayout.setTitle(getResources().getString(R.string.text_shi));

        toolbarTextAppernce();
    }

    private void toolbarTextAppernce() {
        collapsingToolbarLayout.setCollapsedTitleTextAppearance(R.style.collapsedappbar);
        collapsingToolbarLayout.setExpandedTitleTextAppearance(R.style.expandedappbar);
    }

}
```

**ACTUALIZACIÓN:**

***ListViewAdapter:***

```
    public class ListViewAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
        // Declare Variables
        Context context;
        String[] titulos;
        int[] imagenes;
        LayoutInflater inflater;

        public ListViewAdapter(Context context, String[] titulos, int[] imagenes) {
            this.context = context;
            this.titulos = titulos;
            this.imagenes = imagenes;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return titulos.length;
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int position) {
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return 0;
        }

        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

            // Declare Variables
            TextView txtTitle;
            ImageView imgImg;
// ------------------------------------------- NUEVO 

 String[] titulos = context.getResources().getStringArray(R.array.titulos); //Obtiene Array.

//----------------------------------------------

            inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

            View itemView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_row, parent, false);

            // Locate the TextViews in listview_item.xml
            txtTitle = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.list_row_title);
            imgImg = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.list_row_image);

            // Capture position and set to the TextViews
            txtTitle.setText(titulos[position]);
            imgImg.setImageResource(imagenes[position]);

            return itemView;
        }
    }
```

***String.xml***

```
<string-array name="titulos">
    <item>Uno</item>
    <item>Dos</item>
    <item>Tres</item>
    <item>Cuatro</item>
    <item>Cinco</item>
</string-array>
```

Con estas modificaciones ya puedo modificar el texto desde el ***string.xml*** pero yo utilizo ***ListViewAdapter*** para distintas ***clases*** y al hacer estas modificaciones en todas las ***clases*** obtengo los mismos textos, los de ese ***array*** y necesito que sean diferentes en cada ***clase*** pero usando la misma ***ListViewAdapter***. Obviamente sin tener que crear diferentes ***ListViewAdapter***

:::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

***ACTUALIZACIÓN 2:***

***string.xml***

```
<resources>
    <string-array name="titulos">
        <item>Uno</item>
        <item>Dos</item>
        <item>Tres</item>
        <item>Cuatro</item>
        <item>Cinco</item>
    </string-array>

    <string-array name="titulos1">
        <item>Seis</item>
        <item>Siete</item>
        <item>Ocho</item>
        <item>Nueve</item>
        <item>Diez</item>
    </string-array>
</resources>
```

***ListViewAdapter:***

```
    public class ListViewAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

        int[] idArray;

public ListViewAdapter(Context context, String[] titulos, int[] imagenes, int[] idArray) {

    this.idArray = idArray;
```

---

```
    String[] titulos = context.getResources().getStringArray(R.array.titulos); //Obtiene Array.
```

***Clase:***

```
 int[] idArray = {
 R.array.titulos1,
};

---

adapter = new ListViewAdapter(this, titulo, imagenes, idArray);
```

Comment: No es buena práctica tener una clase que comience con una minúscula. `cat_s` Resérvate a sólo poner minúsculas a tus variables e instancias.

Comment: Qué problema puede haber? Siempre lo he hecho así y nunca he tenido problemas, qué problema puede haber? Gracias @marlonpya

Comment: Es un standard de programación (en lo que respecta a JAVA), **Los nombres de variables deben utilizar mayúsculas y minúsculas iniciando con minúscula.** Es una práctica común en la comunidad de desarrollo Java y también la convención de nomenclatura de nombres de variables utilizada por Sun para los paquetes predefinidos de Java. Esta hace que las variables sean fáciles de distinguir de los tipos y resuelve de
manera efectiva las posibles colisiones de nombre como en la declaración `Line line;`

Comment: Gracias lo tendré en cuenta a partir de ahora @marlonpya

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Podrías definir dentro del archivo `strings.xml` ubicado dentro de `/res/values`

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

un array con los valores:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string-array name="titulos">
        <item>Prueba1</item>
        <item>Prueba2</item>
        <item>Prueba3</item>
        <item>Prueba4</item>
        <item>Prueba5</item>
    </string-array>
</resources>
```

**Para obtener los valores del array** se obtendrían de esta forma:

```
String[] titulos = context.getResources().getStringArray(R.array.titulos);
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**también puedes acceder a cada elemento individualmente en base a su indice**:

```
 String titulo = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.titulos)[position];
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

---

Si deseas definir tu `array` en el código, debe ser debe ser dentro del `Adapter` preferentemente:

```
public class ListViewAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    // Declare Variables
    Context context;
    String[] titulos;
    int[] imagenes;
    LayoutInflater inflater;

 String[] titulo = new String[]{
        "Prueba1",
        "Prueba2",
        "Prueba3",
        "Prueba4",
        "Prueba5",
};

...
...
...
```

De esta forma dentro de `getView()` obtendrías los valores correctamente contenidos en el array y se mostraran en el `TextView`:

```
 txtTitle.setText(titulos[position]);
```

---

**Para acceder el array desde otra clase** se define como `public static`:

```
 public static String[] titulo = new String[]{
            "Prueba1",
            "Prueba2",
            "Prueba3",
            "Prueba4",
            "Prueba5",
    };
```

y lo Accedes de esta forma suponiendo que la clase donde fue definido el array es `MainActivity`:

```
  String[] titulos = MainActivit.titulo;
```

---

**Actualización:**

De acuerdo a tu pregunta deseas los elementos en Strings.xml entonces declaras dentro de este archivo el array:

```
   <string-array name="titulos">
        <item>Prueba1</item>
        <item>Prueba2</item>
        <item>Prueba3</item>
        <item>Prueba4</item>
        <item>Prueba5</item>
    </string-array>
```

código `getView()` de acuerdo a tu pregunta:

```
 public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        // Declare Variables
        TextView txtTitle;
        ImageView imgImg;

         String[] titulos = context.getResources().getStringArray(R.array.titulos); //Obtiene Array.

        inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        View itemView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_row, parent, false);

        // Locate the TextViews in listview_item.xml
        txtTitle = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.list_row_title);
        imgImg = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.list_row_image);

        // Capture position and set to the TextViews
        txtTitle.setText(titulos[position]);
        imgImg.setImageResource(imagenes[position]);

        return itemView;
    }
```

Comment: Los comentarios no deben usarse para discusiones extendidas; esta conversación ha sido [trasladada a un chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/52973/discussion-on-answer-by-jorgesys-cambiar-texto-por-getstring-en-mi-listview).

Comment: Lo que me has comentado me ha servido, pero no del todo, ya puedo modificar los textos desde el string.xml con el array, pero, utilizo el mismo listviewadapter para muchas clases, y al modificar lo que me comentas en el listviewadapter tengo los mismos textos en todas las clases.. cómo hago para seguir usando el mismo listviewadapter para todas las clases pero con diferentes textos en el array @Jorgesys ? dejo arriba el nuevo código con tus modificaciones

Comment: Puedes crear diferentes arrays en strings.xml, el ListViewAdapter recibiría en el contructor el id del array a cargar desde strings.xml : public ListViewAdapter(Context context, String[] titulos, int[] imagenes, int idArray) { @UserNameYo

Comment: Gracias @Jorgesys! Solucionado queda, os marque a ti y a @pablo como soluciones ya que me sirvió su respuesta para terminar la última parte de mi código, gracias a ambos !

Answer (score 1):

```
int[] titulo = new int[]{
     R.string.prueba_1;
     R.string.prueba_2;
     R.string.prueba_3;
     R.string.prueba_4;
     R.string.prueba_5;
```

En `ListViewAdapter` cambia:

```
    // Capture position and set to the TextViews
    txtTitle.setText(titulos[position]);
```

a

```
    // Capture position and set to the TextViews
    txtTitle.setText(getResources().getString(titulo[position]));
```

Lo mismo puedes hacer con los imagenes si quieres.

Comment: He añadido mi activity y mi listviewadapter a la pregunta, porque la solución que me das no funciona, estropea todo el código de la activity @StefanNolde

Comment: Sigue sin funcionar con la edición, marca más errores que antes @StefanNolde

Comment: Disculpa, tuve un error de tipografía en el código. Agregaste prueba_1 - prueba_5 a tu strings.xml?

Comment: Sí, tengo dos errores, en listviewadapter. cannot find symbol method getResources() y en la activity, incompatible types: int[] cannot be converted to String[] @StefanNolde

Comment: Tienes que agregar a tu pregunta (a lo mejor abajo indicándolo como cambios) donde hiciste los cambios. Primera sospecha es que no cambiaste la declaración del arreglo como le hice en mi sugerencia de refacturación.

Comment: En todo caso no trata de mezclar el método mío y el método de Jorgesys, ambos te pueden funcionar, pero si lo mezclas te vas a encontrar en un mundo de dolor con los errores. Elige uno con que te sientes mejor y sigue con la implementación.  :)

Comment: He añadido a la pregunta los únicos cambios, también añadido prueba_X a mi string.xml, que hago con tu respuesta @StefanNolde , me sentiría cómoda con ambos, pero de momentos ninguno me funciona jaja, gracias !

Answer (score 1):

En /res/values creas tu fichero strings.xml, idioma por defecto.

En /res/values-es creas tu fichero strings.xml, para castellano.

En /res/values-fr creas tu fichero strings.xml, para francés.
Etc, etc

En cada uno de esos ficheros, en el idioma correspondiente:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string name="title">My Application</string>
    <string name="hello_world">Hello World!</string>
</resources>
```

Finalmente, en Java, accede a esos literales por medio de R.string.title o 
R.string.hello_world.

Aplicando esto a tu código, añadirías los cinco textos "Prueba", y accediendo a ellos por R.string.pruebaX

Para poder obtener la lista de titulos que quieres en cada momento:

```
public class ListViewAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
        // Declare Variables
        Context context;
        String[] titulos;
        int idListaTitulos;

    public ListViewAdapter(Context context, String[] titulos, int[] imagenes, int idListaTitulos) {
            this.context = context;
            this.titulos = titulos;
            this.imagenes = imagenes;
            this.idListaTitulos = idListaTitulos;
        }
    ...
    String[] titulos = context.getResources().getStringArray(idListaTitulos);
    ...
    }
```

Y en los Activity:
    public class cat_s extends AppCompatActivity {

```
...
adapter = new ListViewAdapter(this, titulo, imagenes, R.array.titulos);
```

o

```
adapter = new ListViewAdapter(this, titulo, imagenes, R.array.titulos1);
```

Comment: Lo de las carpetas xml lo sabía, el problema es hacer lo de R.string en esa parte del código en java que pregunto, no se soluciona como me comentas @pablo gracias por responder

Comment: Comprueba que se está compilando bien todo el proyecto y que se genera el fichero R.java con los textos.

Comment: incompatible types: int cannot be converted to string @pablo

Comment: Con getResources().getString(R.string.text_1)?

Comment: Se detiene la aplicación, logcat me marca:  Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.res.Resources android.content.Context.getResources()' on a null object reference

Comment: ¿Puedes copiar el código actualizado?

Comment: Acabo de actualizar @pablo

Comment: Gracias @pablo! Solucionado queda, os marco a ti y a @Jorgesys como soluciones ya que la última parte del código la he solucionado con tu respuesta, gracias a ambos !